# simple React component issue

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I have hte below html, css and JS
HTML:

```
<div id="app1"></div>
```

JS:

```
function hello(props){
  return(
  <div className="Person">
    <h1>Name: {props.name}</h1>
    <p>Age: {props.age}</p>
  </div>
  );
}

var app=(
<div>
  <hello name="John" age="82"/>
  <hello name="Jane" age="89"/>
</div>
);

ReactDOM.render(app,document.querySelector("#app1"));
```

CSS

```
.Person{
  width:200px;
  color:black;
  box-shadow:0 2px 2px #ccc;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:10px;
  padding:2px;
}
```

But this code only works if we have the component name as `Person` anyother name cause the below error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Person is not defined 
 at pen.js:-5
Uncaught ReferenceError: Person is not defined 
 at pen.js:-4
```

you can assume `Reactjs` and `ReactDOM` were imported.

Comment: Check https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html , there is the following note
"React treats components starting with lowercase letters as DOM tags", so in order to use your own component always start component names with a capital letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the first letter of `hello` to capitol like `Hello` (the error with only that code seems a caching thing probably didnt compiled because of having the jsx element there without uppercase) you could instead call in the code `{hello('john', 82)}` as alternative

Comment: yes it did work...But is it so opinionated in react..? BTW..I am just starting on react..so pardon my novice questions

Comment: @Programmerzzz React assumes every component starting with a lowercase name is an html element.

Comment: To call component without 'H' we could use ` {hello('John',82)}
  {hello('Jane',89)}` like Santiago said..Documenting here for someone who may find it useful.Also in this case, we can change the component definition/Signature as `function hello(name,age)` similar to regular JS function.